# Ошибка при запуске бота телеграм ирис чат-бот

Tags: python, aiogram

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDjUt.png) **При запуске бота а точнее bot.py нажимаю Run Module, по началу всё нормально и через 2-3 секунды выдаёт данную ошибку:**

ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 119, in check_result
exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)
File "C:\Users\glebs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

**!!! При этом запущен только один bot.py в IDLE**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускаю с помощью IDLE 3.10.10 (32-bit)

Comment: убедитесь, что запущен только один экземпляр бота

Comment: запущен один, это точно

Comment: вы уверены что ваш токен не использует кто-то другой?

Comment: ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА, спасибо за помощь Сергей Ш, оказывается я сменил токен и проблемы пропали, спасибо огромное!

Comment: Создайте новый токен бота в BotFather

Comment: Не добавляйте "решено" в заголовок. Либо напишите ответ и поставьте на нем галочку, либо удалите вопрос.